# Cannot get XML string by URL

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, webclient

I need to get a string from an external xml by URL.
Code:

```
var client = new WebClient();
string response = client.DownloadString("http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml");
```

But instead I get this response:

```
<html><body onload='resend();'>
<script>
function resend() {
    document.cookie="sto-idd=1954f1298f08833b; max-age=1; path=/";
    window.location.reload();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't figure out what I'm missing, a set cookie? How do you install them correctly?

I've tried installing them like this

```
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie,"max-age=1");
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie,"sto-idd={some id}");
```

Comment: I'd suspect that's some sort of anti-bot protection kicking in. Try changing your web client's user agent to begin with...

Answer (score 1):

I was mistaken, and it is indeed possible to get the XML.
This is a console application.
The Console.Readline() is there so that the console does not close.

With this code you have an XmlDocument with the data you are looking to get.

I hope this helps you.

```
static async Task Main()
{
    string url = "https://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml";

    try
    {
        // Fetch the XML data
        string xmlData = await FetchXmlData(url);

        // Parse the XML data
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlData);

        // Now you can work with the XML data as needed
        // For example, print the tag of the root element
        Console.WriteLine("Root Element Tag: " + xmlDoc.DocumentElement.Name);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}


static async Task<string> FetchXmlData(string url)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        // Send a GET request to the URL
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

        // Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Read the content as a string
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception($"Error: Unable to retrieve XML data. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The data is very much in XML format. It's styled with XSL to look like HTML in your browser. Try viewing the source and looking at the three first lines.

Comment: You are right. It is indeed XML that gets stylised. I thought it'd be something like that, but did not think of XSL.
When looking at the source you can see the XML before it gets transformed.

Comment: @AKX I have edited my answer. Thanks for leading me in the right direction.

Comment: Okay, but the problem wasn't the code. Using https instead of http solves the problem (although it used to work with http)
Thanks anyway, I saw it thanks to your example!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, but the problem wasn't the code. Using *https* instead of *http* solves the problem.